# Integer type keys turned to string type after using json.dump()

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a CSV file that has two columns, one for French words and one for English words:

```
French,English
partie,part
histoire,history
chercher,search
seulement,only
police,police
```

I tried to change the CSV data to JSON but faced an error. My index, which I wanted to be an integer, appeared to be a string. Tried to use int() also but looks like it won't fix this.

How can I change index values to integer inside the JSON file?

```
import json
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("data/french_words.csv")
words = {int(index): {
    "French": row.French,
    "English": row.English,
    "known": None
    } for index, row in data.iterrows()
}
data.update(words)
with open("words.json", mode="w") as words_file:
    json.dump(words, words_file, indent=4)

print(words)
```

Output:

```
{
0: {'French': 'partie', 'English': 'part', 'known': None}, 
1: {'French': 'histoire', 'English': 'history', 'known': None}, 
2: {'French': 'chercher', 'English': 'search', 'known': None}, 
3: {'French': 'seulement', 'English': 'only', 'known': None}, 
4: {'French': 'police', 'English': 'police', 'known': None}, 
5: {'French': 'pensais', 'English': 'thought', 'known': None},
}
```

The result contains 100 key, value pairs. I just put first 5 here.

JSON file output

```
{
    "0": {
        "French": "partie",
        "English": "part",
        "known": null
    },
    "1": {
        "French": "histoire",
        "English": "history",
        "known": null
    },
    "2": {
        "French": "chercher",
        "English": "search",
        "known": null
    },
    "3": {
        "French": "seulement",
        "English": "only",
        "known": null
    },
    "4": {
        "French": "police",
        "English": "police",
        "known": null
    },
    "5": {
        "French": "pensais",
        "English": "thought",
        "known": null
    },
}
```

Comment: JSON objects can't have non-string keys. It seems like you want an _array_ (in Python: list) not an object (dictionary).

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe for editing my post

Comment: Ah, i dont have much experiences working with json, and not really sure which datatype i want to use here since i just started to build this small flashcard GUI. I can see its weird using index number as key for a dictionary.
I also dont know many options to solve this so the data will be easy to get and update later on.
As u suggested, should i make a list from this data, put it in a file then import it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't. The [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) standard defines the use of strings for object attribute names. So when you export, python is doing its best to produce useable JSON (by flipping the integer into a string).

The natural solution to this is to pull the CSV file into an array of objects, which will then export cleanly.